# How to find 2nd most highly correlated column/variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am using cars.csv dataset and want to find out the second most highly correlated column eg cars[‘mpg’].corr() gives output as ‘mpg’ itself. I need ‘drat’ output for ‘mpg’ as input

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_max_correlated_column(a):
    return cars.corr()[a].sort_values(ascending=False).index[1]
    
get_max_correlated_column('mpg')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. The example looks for the atribute which is the most correlated to Cylinders and returns EngineSize.

```py
import pandas as pd

correlation = (
    pd.read_csv('CARS.csv')
    .corr()["Cylinders"].nlargest(2)[1:]
)
correlation
```

Output:

```
EngineSize    0.908002
Name: Cylinders, dtype: float64
```